# Crear un Handler para Listener Button en Android

Tags: android

Estoy iniciando en Android y quería saber si es posible crear un `listener` para un `Button` de la siguiente manera:

```
Button saludoBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.saludarBtn);
saludoBtn.setOnClickListener(this.onClickSaludoHandler());
```

y mi `handler`:

```
private void onClickSaludoHandler() {
      Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Hola",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
      return null;
}
```

Concretamente poder tener un `handler` para cada botón, la verdad no encuentro la forma, lo que vi es que se puede implementar `View.OnClickListene`, y luego tener el método `public void onClick(View v)`
Pero me gustaría si es posible crear un `handler` diferente para cada botón y no tener que hacer un `switch` dentro del mismo método.

Aclaro que mi intención es que quede separado el `handler` del metodo que crea el listener, algo como esto:

```
Button saludoBtn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.saludarBtn1);
saludoBtn1.setOnClickListener(this.onClickSaludoHandler1());

Button saludoBtn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.saludarBtn2);
saludoBtn2.setOnClickListener(this.onClickSaludoHandler2());

private void onClickSaludoHandlerButton1() {
      Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Hola btn 1",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
      return null;
}
private void onClickSaludoHandlerButton2() {
      Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Hola btn 2",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
      return null;
}
```

Comment: Hola Pablo me parece que la mejor opción es crear un listener y dentro agregar la lógica para realizar el toast dependiendo de la vista que realizaste clic.

Answer (score 2):

Dependiendo de para que necesites el `Handler` o lo que quieres hacer en cada acción de botón, un ejemplo de como implementarlo o lo que pides seria algo como esto, quizás te sirva para lo que quieres hacer:

```
private Handler messageHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()) {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message message) {

            switch (message.arg1){
                case 0:
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Hola1",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Hola2",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Hola3",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Hola4",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Hola5",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    break;
            }
        }
    };
```

Como recibe el método la forma de validar? de esta forma, que esto puedes hacerlo en tu `onClick`, así:

```
        messageToSend = Message.obtain();
        messageToSend.arg1=3;
        messageHandler.sendMessage(messageToSend);
```

De esta forma estas enviando un mensaje, con el numero de la acción que deseas realizar. Y el método `messageHandler` en este caso, recibe el valor y ejecuta la acción según el `switch`. Y por supuesto sin olvidar la declaración global de la variable `messageToSend`:

```
private Message messageToSend;
```

También puede usarse para mostrar un `AlertDialog` por ejemplo, pero es como te comente, depende de que quieras hacer con este `Handler`.

Answer (score 2):

Si lo que deseas es tenerlo separado, puedes crear un listener para cada botón:

```
Button saludoBtn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.saludarBtn1);
Button saludoBtn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.saludarBtn2);

    saludoBtn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
               //...........
            }
        });

    saludoBtn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
               //...........
            }
        });
```

pero lo más optimo sería crear un `listener`, asignarlo a los botones y dentro del método `onClick()` definir la lógica.

Crea una variable para el listener:

```
private View.OnClickListener listener;
```

posteriormente crea el `listener` y asignalo a los botones:

```
Button saludoBtn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.saludarBtn1);
Button saludoBtn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.saludarBtn2);

listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(v.getId() == R.id.saludarBtn1){
                   Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Hola btn 1",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                }else if(v.getId() == R.id.saludarBtn2){
                   Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Hola btn 2",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                }

            }
          };

//Asigna listener a botones
saludoBtn1.setOnClickListener(listener);
saludoBtn2.setOnClickListener(listener);
```

Answer (score 0):

Claro puedes invocar el metodo `setOnClickListener` para cada boton:

```
saludoBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Hola",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Si, esto lo vi, pero...
Mi intencion es tener separado el handler, o sea que no este dentro del new del metodo setOnClickListener, algo como esto:

saludoBtn.setOnClickListener(this.onClickListenerButton1());

y luego dentro de mi clase tener declarados los handlers

public void onClickListenerButton1()
{
    // aca hago todo lo que quiero para mi boton particular
}

Answer (score 0):

La solucion a lo que queres es simple

te comparto una porcion de codigo que seguro lo vas a entender a la perfeccion

```
public class f_Alertas extends Fragment/Activity implements  View.OnClickListener {

 @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.saludarBtn:
              //hacer algo
              break;
    }
 }

}
```

Lo que tienes que hacer es siple, si es un fragment o activity tenes que implementar View.OnClickListener y sobrescribir su metodo onClick()

y en u metodo onCreate() o onStart(), el que te resulte mas comodo, yo generalmente lo hago en el onStart() poner el siguiente codigo

```
findViewById(R.id.saludarBtn).setOnClickListener(this);
```

Con esto estarias implementando el handler

Hay una segunda opcion si es una activity.
Deberas crear los metodos que quieras implementar para tus botones pidiendo por parametro una view

```
public void metodoBoton(View v) { ... }
```

en tu XML de la vista, seteas el onClick del boton, por ejemplo

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/boton1"
    ....
    android:onClick="metodoBoton"/>
```

Tercera y ultima opcion que servira tambien para tener cada handler por separado sin tocar XML

```
findViewById(R.id.saludarBtn).setOnClickListener(this::metodoBoton);
```